# Trying to get muliple COUNT(id) from 2 different tables based on the selection from a previous table

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get all of the 'krits' for a specific member and get COUNT(id) the number of rows with kritID from 2 other tables.

This is what I have so far but it does not get accurate numbers it seems like the counts have been added to each other. In each of the returned kritID's.

Is it possible to get separate counts for each with a single SQL query?

```
SELECT  krit.id, krit.short_url, COUNT(referring_url) AS views , COUNT(click_date) AS clicks

FROM ukritic_krits AS krit
LEFT JOIN ukritic_krits_stats AS views ON views.kritID = krit.id
LEFT JOIN ukritic_links_out AS clicks ON clicks.kritID = krit.id

WHERE (krit.memberID = '[LOGGED IN MEMBER ID]')

GROUP BY krit.id
```

P.S. Some of the returned counts my be 0 but I still need that value returned in the resulting rows

Comment: can u post some sample data and desired o/p

Comment: SELECT krit.id, krit.short_url, 
       COUNT(referring_url) AS views, 
       COUNT(click_date) AS clicks    
    FROM ukritic_krits AS krit
        LEFT JOIN ukritic_krits_stats AS views 
            ON views.kritID = krit.id
        LEFT JOIN ukritic_links_out AS clicks 
            ON clicks.kritID = krit.id    
    WHERE (krit.memberID = '".$_SESSION['loggedId']."')    
    GROUP BY krit.id

Comment: That is the current query and I get all the results but when there are two counts both are the same eg.


Array
(
    [id] => 96
    [short_url] => Bose-Lifestyle-V35-Home-Entertainment-System
    [views] => 376
    [clicks] => 376
)

But this one is OK because there are no clicks
Array
(
    [id] => 108
    [short_url] => peter-leeds-penny-stocks
    [views] => 252
    [clicks] => 0
)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [`COUNT(DISTINCT)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count-distinct):

```
SELECT 
    krit.id, krit.short_url, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT views.id) AS views, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT click.id) AS clicks
FROM ukritic_krits AS krit
LEFT JOIN ukritic_krits_stats AS views ON views.kritID = krit.id
LEFT JOIN ukritic_krits_stats AS clicks ON clicks.kritID = krit.id
WHERE (krit.memberID = '[LOGGED IN MEMBER ID]')
GROUP BY krit.id
```

My guess is that the problem you're seeing is that the total counts will equal the number of `views` multiplied by the number of `clicks`, since every matching `view` record is then `left joined` to every matching `clicks` record.  By doing `COUNT(DISTINCT)`, you only count each unique `ID` instead of all the rows.

---

**EDIT:**

The query in your question changed, so since I have to edit anyways, it may be more efficient to use sub-selects in this case instead of `LEFT JOINs`, since you would avoid a distinct operations... but you should of course test:

```
SELECT  
    krit.id, 
    krit.short_url, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ukritic_krits_stats WHERE kritID = krit.id) AS views, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ukritic_links_out WHERE kritID = krit.id) AS clicks
FROM ukritic_krits AS krit
WHERE (krit.memberID = '[LOGGED IN MEMBER ID]')
```

Comment: I updated the sql query in the question with where it is currently at.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT krit.id, krit.short_url, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN views.id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS views, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN click.id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS clicks    
    FROM ukritic_krits AS krit
        LEFT JOIN ukritic_krits_stats AS views 
            ON views.kritID = krit.id
        LEFT JOIN ukritic_krits_stats AS clicks 
            ON clicks.kritID = krit.id    
    WHERE (krit.memberID = '[LOGGED IN MEMBER ID]')    
    GROUP BY krit.id
```

Comment: I updated the sql query in the question with where it is currently at.